# Asiana + Air New Zealand codeshare flight

Tags: air-travel, air-new-zealand, asiana-airlines

I will have a flight from Seoul, Incheon -> Tokyo, Narita -> Auckland, NZ -> Sydney, Australia, all in one booking. The first flight is operated by Asiana Airline, while the rest will be operated Air New Zealand.

My question is if I can get all 3 flight boarding passes when checking in at Incheon airport with Asiana? I notice that Seoul-Tokyo is a codeshare flight between Asiana & ANZ, but onward flights from Tokyo-Auckland-Sydney are solely operated by ANZ.

My flight is due next week so any advice now is highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that in some situations you will not get a boarding pass for connecting flights, mostly if the departure time is too far in the future and check-in is not yet open for that flight. In that case, you normally get subsequent boarding passes from a transfer desk at the connecting airport (or you may be able to get it via the app or online). Your luggage should still be checked through, and you should not need to go through immigration, nor retrieve your bags, not check-in at a regular check-in desk. But your best bet is to contact your airline if you have any doubts.

Comment: Of course, this is considering there are no overnight connections in airports which would not allow them.

Answer (score 1):

> I will have a flight from Seoul, Incheon -> Tokyo, Narita -> Auckland, NZ -> Sydney, Australia, all in one booking.

As it is in one booking, in most cases you should be able to check-in once and you will have all of your boarding passes available at the same time.

> My question is if I can get all 3 flight boarding passes when checking in at Incheon airport with Asiana?

You might have to check with the airline. You can check online right now by viewing your booking and seeing if it displays all 3 flights or are they separate. It is better to arrive to the airport with time to spare just in case.

> I notice that Seoul-Tokyo is a codeshare flight between Asiana & ANZ, but onward flights from Tokyo-Auckland-Sydney are solely operated by ANZ.

It may well be that you have to get boarding passes for the first 2 flights and separately for the 3rd flight, this has to be checked in your booking/with the airline.

Comment: Both OZ and NZ are Star Alliance partners, so I would expect to get all boarding passes at check-in.  If not, any transit desk can sort you out. I'd be more concerned about visa requirements for transit...